# Blink leds while switches are pressed in Tiva C

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I'm trying to make the PF0 and PF4 leds blink while the switches are pressed. But it simply does not turn on any leds.

I was told I needed to use two ports, I don't see why, since this can be done with only one port — in this case the port D — but it was suggested that I use the port K as well (?).
The board is a Tiva C [TM4c1294nctpd](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c1294ncpdt.pdf)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/debug.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include <inc/tm4c1294ncpdt.h>

uint32_t SW1,SW2; //

int main(void) {

    while(1){
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R=0X1100; // Enable port D
    GPIO_PORTD_DIR_R=0X03;      //enable the GPIO pin PN0, 
    GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R=0X03;  
    GPIO_PORTK_AHB_DIR_R=0;
    GPIO_PORTK_AHB_DEN_R=0X03;
    GPIO_PORTK_AHB_PUR_R=0X01;

    SW1 = GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R&0x10;     // read PF4 into SW1
    SW2 = GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R&0x01;     // read PF0 into SW2
    if (!SW1 && !SW2) { // both pressed
        GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x04;
    } else if (!SW1) { // SW1 pressed
        GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x02;
    } else if (!SW2) { // SW2 pressed
        GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x08;
    } else { // neither
        GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x00;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: There are no loops in `main()`. What happens at the end of the function? And do you hold the switches pressed while the device is powered up?

Comment: You told us the MCU but you didn't tell us the board.  Share a link to the board schematic so we can see how the LEDs and switches are connected to the MCU.  Doesn't "PF4" mean port F pin 4?  Why are you using port D then?  Is PF4 the LED as you state in your question, or is it the switch as you write in your code?

Comment: @WeatherVane, yup, added a while to make it happens continuosly

Comment: @kkrambo, added the datasheet

Comment: Please don't just add random code: there is no need to keep re-initialising the on-board devices. Where are you "blinking the LEDs"?

Comment: @WeatherVane, sorry bro, Im used to  use the while this way, it is not random code.

Comment: Looks like [cargo-cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) code to me.  The I/O initialisation bares no relationship to the I/O used.

Comment: @riccs_0x : You have missed WV's point.  The code you post should be the code that you are running and which exhibits the problem.  The original "fake" code bearing a passing resemblance to the actual code is useless - it would have exhibited exactly the symptoms you described - i.e. nothing happens, so it would be reasonable to assume that was your problem and someone might reasonably post an answer to that effect - wasting their time and taking longer for you to get an answer.

Comment: Comments are pointless if they do not accurately reflect the code - are the switches on PORTD or PORTF?  You have a reference to PORTN in a PORTD related comment too. And `\\ int 1` !?  With the scan information in the question, accurate and useful comments would help.

Comment: @Clifford, the int 1 part its simply a reference I used in other code, this is a typo,

Comment: Fine but you should really fix the other issues with your question too. Such as clarify which port/pins the switches and LEDs are actually connected to - you can't arbitrarily choose a port, it must be the one the hardware is connected to!  The question mentions PORTF, PORTD and PORTK but you say you want to use _just one_.  Unless you believe whoever told you you need to use PORTK to know what they are talking about, that information is irrelevant.

Comment: I think I have figured out what you have.  Your link is to the microcontroller not the board.  If you are using the [EK-TM4C1294XL](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu365c/spmu365c.pdf) board, then the LEDs are _called_ D1,D2,D3,D4 (D for _diode_, not _PORTD), but are on GPIOs PN1, PN0, PF4 and PF0 respectively, and the switches are on PJ0 and PJ1.  So nothing is on Port D and you do indeed need to access _three_ ports.  If you have different hardware or have added your own switch/LED hardware you need to be clear, because if you have this board, this question and my answer are rendered nonsense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have only enabled D0 and D1, but appear to be using D0, D1, D2, D3 and D4.
- You have set D0 and D1 as output, but appear to be be using D1, D2, D3 as outputs.
- You have set D0 as an output, but attempt to read it as an input.
- The configuration of PORTK is entirely irrelevant if you are not using it.
- The RCGCGPIO enables the clock for PORTN and PORTJ which you are not using at all.

I am not familiar with the part and have only briefly read the data sheet, but the the PORTD clock, direction and digital enable configuration should be as follows if the input/output code is itself correct.

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = 0x0008; // Enable port D clock
GPIO_PORTD_DIR_R = 0x0E;    // D4, D0 input, D1 to D3 output.
GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R = 0x1F;    // Enable D0 to D4
```

These *initialisation* settings need be done *once only* - *before* the loop, not *inside* it.

```
int main(void) 
{
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = 0x0008; // Enable port D
    GPIO_PORTD_DIR_R = 0x0E;    // D4, D0 input, D1 to D3 output.
    GPIO_PORTD_DEN_R = 0x1F;    // Enable D0 to D4  

    for(;;)
    {
        uint32_t SW1 = GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R & 0x10;  // read PD4 into SW1
        uint32_t SW2 = GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R & 0x01;  // read PD0 into SW2

        if (!SW1 && !SW2)  // both pressed
        {
            GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x04;
        } 
        else if (!SW1)     // SW1 pressed
        { 
            GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x02;
        } 
        else if (!SW2)     // SW2 pressed
        {
            GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x08;
        } 
        else               // neither 
        { 
            GPIO_PORTD_DATA_R = 0x00;
        }
    }
}
```

---

After thought:

The comments in the presumably copy & pasted code suggest the board might be an [EK-TM4C1294XL](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu365c/spmu365c.pdf).  In that case the the LEDs are *called* D1, D2, D3, D4 (D for *diode*, not _PORTD), but are on GPIOs PN1, PN0, PF4 and PF0 respectively, and the switches are on PJ0 and PJ1.

In that case perhaps the following will be more successful:

```
int main(void) 
{
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= (1<<5 | 1<<8 | 1<<12); // Enable port F, J and N clocks
    GPIO_PORTN_DIR_R |= 0x03;   // PN1 = LED0, PN0 = LED1 (Outputs)
    GPIO_PORTN_DEN_R |= 0x03;   // Enable PN0 and PN1  
    GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R |= 0x11;   // PF4 = LED3, PF0 = LED4 (Outputs)
    GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R |= 0x11;   // Enable PF0 and PF4  

    GPIO_PORTJ_DIR_R &= ~0x03;   // PJ0 = SW1, PJ1 = SW2 (Inputs)
    GPIO_PORTJ_DEN_R &= ~0x03;   // Enable PJ0 and PJ4  

    for(;;)
    {
        uint32_t SW1 = GPIO_PORTJ_DATA_R & 0x01;  // read PJ0 into SW1
        uint32_t SW2 = GPIO_PORTJ_DATA_R & 0x02;  // read PJ1 into SW2

        if (!SW1 && !SW2)  // both pressed
        {
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x01;  // LED4
        } 
        else if (!SW1)     // SW1 pressed
        { 
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x10;  // LED3
        } 
        else if (!SW2)     // SW2 pressed
        {
            GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R = 0x01;  // LED2
        } 
        else               // neither 
        { 
            GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R = 0x02;  // LED1
        }
    }
}
```

This remains broken because the code only ever switches LED's on - an it does not respect other hardware that may be connected to other pins on ports F and N;  you need to add code to read-modify-write the respective pins fo reach LED you set, you need to clear the other three.  I'll leave that to you - it goes beyond the original question.

Comment: Could you tell me please, how can be know the values to enable the ports and the dir and den functions, I always go to the base adress and add the offset at the end, but It seems it isn't done this way

Comment: @riccs_0x : That probably deserves a new question in itself, but is pretty fundamental to embedded systems development.  It is also not clear what you mean by _"[...] base adress and add the offset at the end"_.  For example for DIR, the value 0x0E is binary 00001110 - setting bits 1,2 and 3 to 1 (Output).  The required information comes from the data sheet.

Comment: @riccs_0x : I am beginning to regret attempting to answer this given the ambiguity of your question.  As you can see I have had to make too many guesses and assumptions (and way too much work).  Fix your question by describing unambiguously the hardware your are using, and I can clean up this answer.

Comment: Im sorry you regret the answer, but for me It has been way more useful than my classrom seasons, since the teacher does not explain nothing and I have to make many guesses too, Im  aware of it. But this is very good information, and I think not only for me.